# Question about product measure (from Folland)

Tags: measure-theory

Folland chapter 2, question 51: I did the part (a), but the (b) is a little confusing for me.

(b) Let $(X,M,\mu)$ and $(Y, N,\nu)$ be measure spaces, not necessarily $\sigma$-finite. Let $f\colon X \to \mathbb C$, $f \in L^1(\mu)$, $g\colon Y \to \mathbb C$, $g\in L^1(\nu)$ and $h\colon X\times Y \to \mathbb C$ $M\times N$ - measurable, $h=f\times g$. So $h \in L^1(\mu\times\nu)$ and

\begin{equation}
\int h \,d(\mu\times\nu) = \left(\int f \,d\mu\right)\left(\int g \,d\nu\right).
\end{equation}

What I tried to do:
So I define two new measures that are $\sigma$-finite 
\begin{eqnarray}
m(E) = \int_E f\,d\mu \\
n(F) = \int_F g\,d\nu
\end{eqnarray}

And use Fubini to obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d(m\times n) = \int h \,d\nu d\mu = \int f \,d\mu\int gd\nu
\end{eqnarray}

It's almost done, but I need that this is also equal to 
\begin{equation}
\int h \,d(\mu\times\nu)
\end{equation}

And this I can't see why.

Comment: What does $\int d(m\times \mu \,d\nu$ mean? Also, you should tell us what the exercise is asking you to do...

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I alteady corrected the mistakes, and the exercise is writen there.

Comment: Oh, so you assume that everybody has a copy of Folland at hand? It is unclear from what you have written what is given and what is asked to prove.

Comment: i thought i saw a typo but  i didn't. i made no changes

Comment: No @SilviaGhinassi I didn't assume that. What I tried to say, but my english are not so good, and maybe I wrote in a bad way, is that I wrote the question and is writen in the beginen. Some one changed my question a little, so I hope it is more clear know.